# Deleting image saved to internal storage if associated database entry is removed or altered

Tags: android, sqlite, storage, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm creating a logging app where the user creates an entry to an SQLite database, with several text fields. They also have to option to capture an image of the item.

The picture is saved (named with a dd-mm-yy_hh-mm-ss.jpg filename) to internal app directory (imageDir), the path of which is entered into the database entry so it can be displayed along with the item text in both a list view and a detail view.

Currently, if the database item is removed, or the picture updated, the old picture remains in the internal directory.

Obviously over time these orphaned photos will amount to a sizable chunk of storage space. So how can I check for orphaned pictures and remove them automatically?

Comment: You can get the files with jpg extension using `File` class method  `File().listFiles()` or `DocumentFile` class method `DocumentFile.listFiles()` both returns array for files inside your app's folder and compare their names with the ones in database. If they don't match delete the image.

Comment: What would be the best way to implement this? Sorry I'm very new to coding.